# Typescript error: Type 'undefined[]' is not assignable to type 'void'

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

In my Angular app I have a filter function that keeps track of both user inputed filter values, and whether or not those filter values are currently enabled/active. I am initializing these filters like so:

```
filters = { language: [], location: [], zipArray: [], firstName: [], lastName: [] };
```

I am running into a Typescript error with this section of code -- specifically this line: `return this.filters.zipArray = [];`

```
public onZipcodeEnabledChange(enabled): void {
    this.filters.zipArray = this.getZipcodeArray();
    if (!enabled || this.filters.zipArray && this.filters.zipArray[0] === ''){
        return this.filters.zipArray = [];
    }
}
```

The TypeScript error I'm getting is:

> Type 'undefined[]' is not assignable to type 'void'.

I'm not understanding what the issue is here?

Comment: You have the return type of `onZipcodeEnabledChange` as `void`, but you're returning an empty array. Try writing `return;` on its own line after you set the `zipArray` filters.

Comment: void means it doesnt return anything and you have 2 issues 1 you're returning an assignment and two you're returning something if you want to resolve :  string[]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You declared return type of `onZipcodeEnabledChange` as void it means that function will not return anything. And in if statement, you are returning assignment result of `return this.filters.zipArray = [];` i.e. [].

> **Solution 1**

Just remove return keyword will work for you.

```
public onZipcodeEnabledChange(enabled): void {
    this.filters.zipArray = this.getZipcodeArray();
    if (!enabled || this.filters.zipArray && this.filters.zipArray[0] === ''){
       this.filters.zipArray = [];
    }
}
```

> **Solution 2**

And if you want to return array from that function, you need to replace void with `any[]`.

```
public onZipcodeEnabledChange(enabled): any[] {
    this.filters.zipArray = this.getZipcodeArray();
    if (!enabled || this.filters.zipArray && this.filters.zipArray[0] === ''){
       this.filters.zipArray = [];
       return this.filters.zipArray;
    }
}
```

Comment: and vis vera if you do want to return you'll have to change void to : any[] or string[]  whatver the type the stuff in the array

Comment: Great. Thanks. Will make this change.

Comment: @JoeWarner, Absolutely, I updated the answer. Thanks :)

Comment: lol i was typing my answer out you beat me too it xD good stuff

Comment: With Solution 2, like @JoeWarner mentioned, I would suggest typing the method return type instead of using `any` whilst also typing the properties here, you could initialise this something like `zipArray: ['value1']` with the values, also I would recommend moving the return outside of the if block, so both paths return the same type for readability and this methods caller.